# Selecting data between two dates in Dataframe 'ValueError: Lengths must match to compare'

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, dataframe, datetime, types

I want to select all the values that are between 2 dates in my large `df_data`. This works when I do this outside of a loop for a single day worth of data:

```
df_data['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df_data['TimeStamp'] )
twelveearlier = datetime.datetime(2017, 12,23, 00,00, 00)
twelvelater = datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 24, 00, 00, 00)

df = df_data[(df_data['datetime']>= twelveearlier) &
         (df_data['datetime']< twelvelater)]
```

But when I try and do this by looping through a list of dates below, I get `ValueError: Lengths must match to compare`.

```
event_name_list = ['noEvent_20161208174900', 'NoEvent_20161209174200', 'NoEvent20161211_061400']

    for event in event_name_list:
        event_time = re.findall(r'\d+', event)
        event_timestamp = pd.to_datetime(event_time)
        twelvelater = event_timestamp + datetime.timedelta(hours=12)
        twelveearlier = event_timestamp - datetime.timedelta(hours=12)

        df = df_data[(df_data['datetime']>= twelveearlier.values) &
                 (df_data['datetime']< twelvelater.values)]
```

I think this is because twelveearlier and twelvelater are different types in the loop
version due to using `event_timestamp - datetime.timedelta(hours=12)`but converting them using `to_datetime`, `to_pydatetime` etc. doesn't help. How do I get `twelveearlier` and `twelvelater` in the same format as `df_data[`datetime`]` so that I can create `df` based on only the dates between `twelveearlier` and `twelvelater`?

```
df_data['datetime']
3250592   2017-12-31 23:40:00
3250593   2017-12-31 23:50:00
Name: datetime, dtype: datetime64[ns]

print event_timestamp
DatetimeIndex(['2016-12-16 06:22:29'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)

print twelveearlier
DatetimeIndex(['2016-12-08 05:49:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)

print twelvelater
DatetimeIndex(['2016-12-09 05:49:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to compare against a list of date times:`twelvelater.values` gives you a single element array.

This means you are trying to match a dataframe against 'multiple' elements in the conditional [[datetime]]. Only taking the first element of each of these date time arrays `twelvelater.values[0]` should fix the problem with minimal code changes.

```
event_name_list = ['noEvent_20161208174900', 'NoEvent_20161209174200', 'NoEvent20161211_061400']

for event in event_name_list:
        event_time = re.findall(r'\d+', event)
        event_timestamp = pd.to_datetime(event_time)
        twelvelater = event_timestamp + datetime.timedelta(hours=12)
        twelveearlier = event_timestamp - datetime.timedelta(hours=12)

        df = df_data[(df_data['datetime']>= twelveearlier.values[0]) &
                 (df_data['datetime']< twelvelater.values[0])]
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. I had tried `.values` but was sloppy and hadn't used `[0]`

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to compare datetime to a DatetimeIndex of datetimes of length one. This is because `re.findall` returns a list of all the matches it finds. Try this:

```
event_name_list = pd.to_datetime([re.findall(r'\d+', x)[0] for x in event_name_list])

for event_timestamp in event_name_list:
        twelvelater = event_timestamp + datetime.timedelta(hours=12)
        twelveearlier = event_timestamp - datetime.timedelta(hours=12)
        df = df_data[(df_data['datetime']>= twelveearlier) &
                     (df_data['datetime']< twelvelater)]
```